# Ideas of procedural algorithms for generating a grid-based town

Tags: algorithm, unity-game-engine, artificial-intelligence, procedural-generation, procedural

Hope you're alright.

For the last two weeks, I'm trying to find one algorithm for generating procedural cities/towns on a grid system. I'm more focused on the road network than buildings, nature etc.

I've tried L-System (following this tutorial series on YouTube: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLcRSafycjWFcbaI8Dzab9sTy5cAQzLHoy) and some modifications of maze algorithms (explained here: http://weblog.jamisbuck.org/2011/2/7/maze-generation-algorithm-recap), but no success to react what I want.

Searching more, I found this old thread [Generating a city/town on a grid (Simply my approach)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48318881/generating-a-city-town-on-a-grid-simply-my-approach) where that guy created an algorithm that makes exactly what I want. Now I'm trying to understand (and, maybe, simplify) that algorithm to rewrite it on Unity game engine.

So now, I want to know if someone knows other algorithm(s) that makes something next to this: a city/road network based on a grid.

Thank you for your help and for sharing your knowledge! This project is part of my graduate thesis and, if you can help me, I will be very thankful!

Comment: I would give a llok to the [assetStore](https://assetstore.unity.com/?q=city%20generator&orderBy=1). There migth be some cool asset close to what you're lookig for

Comment: Yeah for $15 or whatever you can buy an asset and then learn or reuse parts of it's code. I wouldn't recommend using whole assets, usually while building your game you want to customize them anyways and it's better to use them for learning and write your own code.